# Mean Value Theorem applied to $f(x)=\arctan(x)$ on the interval $[0,x]$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have started to use the general form $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ an substituted the derivative of $\arctan(x)$ on the left side while substituting the intervals to the right side and simplifying all the way down by:
\begin{align*}  
\frac{1}{1+x^2} & = \frac{f(0)-f(x)}{0-x}\\
\frac{1}{1+x^2} & = \frac{\arctan(0)-\arctan(x)}{-x}\\
\frac{1}{1+x^2} & = \frac{\arctan(x)}{x}
\end{align*}

What do I do from here because I'm not sure if I've attempted it correctly. How do I find the bounds?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: What do you mean by "find the bounds"? Are you trying to solve for $x$?

Comment: @MorpheusZion: Did you find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\frac{\arctan(x)-\arctan(0)}{x-0}=\frac{1}{1+\xi^2}\le 1$$ where $$\xi \in [0,x]$$